# Trazer valor mais recente de campo considerando casos variáveis

Tags: sql, case, bigquery

Quero que uma consulta me retorne da tabela produtos o valor mais recente atualizado, priorizando sempre a loja 1, porém quando o produto não tiver valor na loja 1, retornar o valor mais recente da loja seguinte que não tenha valor nulo, e assim sucessivamente.

| PRODUTO | PRECO | LOJA | DATA_ATUALIZACAO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 94714 | 20.5 | 1 | 2023-02-04 |
| 94714 | 28.5 | 4 | 2023-02-04 |
| 94714 | 30 | 3 | 2023-02-05 |
| 94714 | 12 | 3 | 2023-02-06 |
| 94714 | 64 | 2 | 2023-02-06 |
| 73268 | 100 | 1 | 2023-02-06 |
| 73268 | 96.4 | 3 | 2023-02-06 |

Montei uma query onde me retorna o valor mais recente atualizado.

```
WITH V AS 
    (
      SELECT
        PRODUTO,
        PRECO,
        LOJA,
        DATA_ATUALIZACAO 
      FROM PRODUTOS AS P
      WHERE PLNT_CD IN ('1', '2', '3','4')
    )

    SELECT V.PRODUTO, V.PRECO, V.LOJA ,P.DT_MAX
    FROM (
          SELECT PRODUTO, MAX(DATA_ATUALIZACAO) as DT_MAX, 
          FROM V
          GROUP BY PRODUTO
    ) P
    INNER JOIN V ON V.PRODUTO = P.PRODUTO AND V.DATA_ATUALIZACAO = P.DT_MAX
```

Tive como resultado essa consulta.

| PRODUTO | PRECO | LOJA | DATA_ATUALIZACAO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 94714 | 12 | 3 | 2023-02-06 |
| 94714 | 64 | 2 | 2023-02-06 |
| 73268 | 100 | 1 | 2023-02-06 |
| 73268 | 96.4 | 3 | 2023-02-06 |

O resultado que gostaria.

| PRODUTO | PRECO | LOJA | DATA_ATUALIZACAO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 94714 | 64 | 2 | 2023-02-06 |
| 73268 | 100 | 1 | 2023-02-06 |

Não filtrei pela loja prioritária pois quando não tiver valor de outro produto nessa mesma loja o produto não retornará.

Comment: O que "desempata" a data quando for igual !?

Comment: A loja com o menor valor

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode usar o **`ORDER BY` '*nome da coluna1, nome da coluna2*' `ASC` ou `DESC`**, para organizar de forma crescente ou decrescente, respectivamente.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).